# Is "get" (in the sense of "become/make") appropriate for formal writing?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, formality

Is the use of "get + adjective/participle" appropriate for formal writing (for example, scientific papers)?  I am thinking of usages analogous to

- get fat
- get inflated
- get sick

where the meaning is "become".  What about cases where the meaning is "make (sg)", such as

- get (it) done
- get (her) dressed

Not being a native speaker, I cannot easily judge the level of formality of these constructs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may depend on the particular research community. I can say, at least in spoken presentations in a workshop or conference, many communities may find using 'get' just fine... but many other communities would not.

I would personally like to avoid 'get' in formal writing, I guess you mean research articles. To be sure, you should try to check if the community you belong to uses it in their literature. But, if its for emails or blogs, it maybe alright.

Comment: Maybe. But it may be all wrong.

Answer (score 5):

*Get* is fine to use if it fits, but it is probably too general for most cases where you might use it in a scientific paper. Consider precise substitutions:

> got a reaction => produced a reaction
>   test subjects got rashes => test subjects exhibited rashes
>   we got results using a .04% solution => results were achieved using a .04% solution

That kind of thing. You can use *get* where appropriate, though:

> In many cases, test subjects got up from their chairs and left the room rather than answer any more questions.

And one place you may definitely use it is in emails to your colleagues:

> Good news! We got our funding! Booyah!

Comment: Not sure if this fits the OP's idea of using get (become/make). See OP's examples.

Comment: @Kris: Well, in chat the OP said it did. But thanks for down-voting an answer you're not sure about based on your interpretation of someone else's idea (which of course you can measure to six decimal places).

Comment: Rather, thanks for your presumption that I down voted you. lol. Down voters mostly don't comment here these days.

Comment: @Kris: The two things happened with apparent simultaneity. Pardon me if I blasted you with "post hoc ergo propter hoc."

Answer (score 5):

*Get* has [a lot of uses](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104219/15299) in English. It's the ***Causative/Inchoative*** form
of **both** *be* and *have*. That is, it can represent either *come to be* (= *become*) or *come to have* when it's inchoative -- Inchoatives are intransitive and refer to change of state -- **or** it can represent either *cause to be* or *cause to have* when it's causative -- Causatives are transitive and refer to causing change.

- **Stative**: *He was tired/sick/here/mad/arrested/writing.*
- **Inchoative** *He got tired/sick/here/mad/arrested/writing.*
- **Causative** *He got me tired/sick/here/mad/arrested/writing.*

Consequently, *get* can be used in most constructions and idioms that involve either *be* or *have*. And there are an awful lot of them.

As far as its usage in scientific papers is concerned, I agree with Karthik that this depends entirely on the traditions of the research community. Nobody should attempt to write (let alone publish) scientific research in any field without having read many, many papers in the same field, and by that time, they should be aware of the traditional writing styles and conventions in their field.

Oh, and most of the examples provided in the OQ are **not** participles, by the way.

Comment: "Nobody should attempt to write (let alone publish) scientific research in any field without having read many, many papers in the same field, and by that time, they should be aware of the traditional writing styles and conventions in their field." <---- You seem to forget that in all sciences most authors are not native speakers of English, and also that us non-native speakers are not nearly as sensitive to differences in nuances, and therefore can't easily form a good picture of the "traditional writing style" (if such a thing exists at all). It is not very nice what you are implying there.

Comment: No implication is intended, except that no one should attempt to publish science without understanding published science, in whatever language is relevant. All people, even scientists, vary greatly in how well they understand, read, and write languages. So I would think it is "not very nice" to claim that non-native speakers of English cannot learn a writing style by example. I've known many who have; and I've also known many native speakers who haven't.