# "He was getting beaten" vs. "he was being beaten"

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, get-be

I would need to understand the difference here:

> He was being beaten.
>   He was getting beaten.

I know "get" + ppt can be either passive voice or a change of state. What is that in this example? I guess this is the passive voice.
But what about this:

> He is getting ready.
>   He is being ready *- obviously wrong but I cannot say why.*

Comment: Related: [Why is to get sometimes used where to be could be used](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/why-is-to-get-sometimes-used-where-to-be-could-be-used)

Answer (score 5):

*Get* is a very busy verb in English.

It's mostly an auxiliary verb, and it almost always is **[Inchoative](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsInchoativeAspect.htm)** in meaning -- i.e, it refers to a change of state, by referring to a state that is beginning.

> Inchoative predicates (verbs and adjectives) often occur in sets of **Stative**, **Inchoative**, and **Causative**, which are often the same word, but sometimes not:
>
> 1. **Stative** predicate:
>      *The gate is open (wide)/(wide) open.*
>      *The gate is closed (tight).*
>      *The dog is dead.*
>      *The dog is tired (out).*
>      *He is (located) at X*.
>      *They have (= possess) the book*.
> 2. **Inchoative** predicate:
>      *The gate opened (wide).*
>      *The gate closed (tight).*
>      *The dog died.*
>      *The dog tired. ~ The dog got tired (out).*
>      *He came/went to X.*
>      *They got (= received) the book.*
> 3. **Causative** predicate:
>      *We opened the gate (wide)*.
>      *We closed the gate (tight).*
>      *We killed the dog.*
>      *We tired the dog (out).*
>      *We brought/took him to X.*
>      *They got (= acquired) the book.*

*Get* is so busy because it's the inchoative of **both** the auxiliary verb *be* **and** the auxiliary verb *have*. And these auxiliary verbs participate in an **awful** lot of constructions. Therefore, so does *get*.

- Some examples of Inchoative uses of *get* (many idiomatic):

> - *He **was** tired.* ~ *He **got** tired.*  (*get* = 'come to *be*')
> - *He **is** moving.* ~  *He **got** moving.*
> - *He **is** married.* ~  *He **got** married.*
> - *He **is being** married.* ~  *He **is getting** married.*
> - *He **is** tired.* ~  *He **got** tired.*
> - *He **has** a cold.* ~  *He **got** a cold.*   (*get* = 'come to *have*')
> - *He **had** it done.* ~  *He **got** it done.*
> - *He **has** the job.* ~ *He **got** the job.*
> - *He **has to** retire.* ~  *He has **got to** retire* ~ *He's **gotta** retire.*

Answer (score 0):

For your second sentence, the [‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582237262)
(and, I suspect, others) uses the term ‘*get*-passive’, commenting that it

> . . . is rare in all registers, but is occasionally used in
>   conversation. Only five verbs have a notable frequency with the
>   get-passive . . . Many of these verbs
>   have a different emphasis when used with the *get*-passive rather than
>   the *be*-passive. With *be*, they express a state, such as the state
>   of 'being married' or 'being involved.' With *get*, they are more
>   dynamic, describing the processing of getting into that state . . .
>   *Get*-passives are typical only in conversation. The written registers usually use *become* instead.

*Get ready* is a phrasal verb and, as such, has a progressive form as in your example. *Be ready* is not a phrasal verb. It is the verb *be* + the adjective *ready*. The progressive form of *be* is not used to describe a state, and that is why ‘He is being ready’ is ungrammatical. The progressive form of *be* can, however, be used to describe an activity. ‘He is stupid’ describes a continuing state, but ‘He is being stupid’ describes something he is doing now.

Comment: Become married, Barrie?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. The LSGSWE does say '**usually**'.

Comment: I've just done a trawl for "get-passive" and found several where the get-passive is semantically different from the be-passive, but _become_ can be substituted: _involved, frightened, tired_. There are some where the _become_ substitution doesn't work, but where the verb alone can be used: _get changed / change_; _get married / marry_. There are others where it's difficult to replace the informal register: _get engaged, broken, caught (in a thornbush etc)_. _Got killed / shot_ / _was killed / shot_ are synonymous, as are _got_ / _was caught_ (by the police etc).

Comment: Really, there should be a different analysis for structures where get is being used as a delexical verb (get washed, get involved, get going, get married) as opposed to 'receiving action from an outside agency' usages, such as get shot, get killed, get caught. I think OP suggests this. There are indeterminate cases (get / be frightened).

Comment: Not sure how the grammatical "being readied" fits in here.

Comment: @horatio: We can say 'Being ready on time is imperative', but we can't say 'He is being ready at the moment' - as Barrie says, 'the progressive form of _be_ is not used to describe a state'. However, the **verb** _ready_ describes a transformational process rather than a state - we **can** say 'Your plane is being readied as we speak.' (It's unusual to use 'ready' with a human object, and I'm guessing that passive constructions with the verb _ready_ are more common than active.) ??Tim is being readied. ?We are readying your room.

Comment: @Barrie England: at http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~gt3/recent-mss/getpassives2.pdf is an analysis of the 'get-passive' and other constructions using _get_; a major and well-argued proposition is that these are not really passive structures at all!