# "Should be" is to "Should become" as "Should have" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to express an assertion that someone should have something, not right now but in the future.

What I'm looking for is analogous to the relationship between "should be" and "should become".

Hence the title of the question: "Should be" is to "Should become" as "Should have" is to "should what?"

Comment: Do you want to emphasize the possession or the acquisition? If the latter, *should receive* or *should acquire* might work.

Comment: The relation (which has nothing to do with _should_, by the way) between _be_ and _become_ does have a name. _Be_ is stative while _become_ is ***Inchoative*** (pronounced /ɪn'kowətɪv/); i.e, it refers to a **change** of state. Many English stative predicates occur with inchoative (and causative) variants, like _(be) dead, die, kill; open, open, open; closed, close, close,_ etc.  As it happens, _get_ is the inchoative of _have_, and **also** of _be_.  So _be_ has three inchoatives: _get, become, come to be_; and have has only one: [_get_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/104219/15299).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Should have` is future tense as well as present tense, so you could use the same word `have`. Notice that `has` is only present tense and that `had` is only past tense, while `have` can be used for both. Similar to `get`, `gets` and `got` and other words like that.

If you really want to use a different word, try `should get` or `should acquire`. Something along those lines should work quite nicely.

Comment: `be` and `become` are also both present tense, but `become` clearly carries the notion of a transition from some state to another. Is there a word with similar notion of transition but used for possession rather than for being?

Comment: I don't think that `be` and `become` are directly related, so any word with that sort of definition should work. Have does not have this type of relative word either.

Comment: Forget about _should_; it's just a modal and can go in front of any infinitive, and it isn't future tense, either.

Comment: @JohnLawler That is just the word the OP was using. It is irrelevant, I agree. I was referring to `have` exclusively in the first sentence.

Comment: _Have_ in _should have_ is an infinitive, and therefore has no tense at all. It is not future tense, because there is no future tense in English. We can refer to the future in English using any tense (past tense or present tense -- the only ones in English) and hundreds of constructions, but future reference is not future tense.  (I'm sorry to have to be the one to tell you that your English teacher was all wrong about tenses.)

Comment: @JohnLawler Whoa! Got a link? I want to read some more about that! That is really odd and really cool at the same time!

Comment: Here's [the way I explained it](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html) in a usenet group 20 years ago. Basically, English has been losing inflections for centuries, and has only two tenses (present and past) left -- where "tense" means 'use [inflections](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) on the main verb', and **not** 'use an auxiliary verb before the main verb'. Those latter are called constructions, not tenses, there are thousands of them, and _will_ is just another modal auxiliary verb.

Answer (score 0):

You could emphasize the future tense by adding in an concrete time reference. Something like this perhaps:

> Her father decided then and there that she should later have his fortune.