# What kind of verb classification is "causative"?

Tags: terminology, causative-verbs, predicate-adjectives

I understand why "causative" verbs like "let" and "allow" are described this way, but I don't understand how this classification relates to other verb descriptors. Is "causative" a peer or child of "transitive" classification, more related to classifications like dynamic, stative, auxiliary, and modal, an attribute that is a part of aspect or mood, or yet another dimension? If the last, are they are other peer classes to "causative"?

Comment: The small set of causative verbs are ones in which the agent uses the object to achieve their own ends. Causative verbs are used causatively rather than being causative, e.g. I had him cut the lawn - I had a car but I sold it / I made him eat it - I made him a cake  /I allowed her to go to the dance - I allow a little extra length for adjustment, etc.

Comment: @Greybeard - If I follow your answer correctly, "let" in "let's try this", is a lexical verb (present simple?) but its usage is "causative" which is a dimension unto itself.  Is causative more a semantic classification rather than a grammatical one then?

Comment: "Let", in "Let's try this", is a causative. The agent, the speaker, has the aim of both he and the listener doing the same thing. He does this, in this case, by the means of persuasion. He has achieved his own ends. I think that the causative can always imply an instrumental.

Answer (score 13):

***Causative*** is a term with a lot of uses, in several different contexts. First, as usual, we start out correcting misimpressions. *Let* and *allow* are not exactly "causative verbs" -- rather, they participate in some causative constructions, as does *have* (as in *I had my tires rotated*). This does not make them causative verbs, however.

Verbs, and other predicates, can describe either events (**Active** predicates) or states (**Stative** predicates). Either events or states can take a long time or a short time; some occur at a point in time, others spread out over a long period. There can be changes -- growth or loss, age, etc. -- and these can be sudden or gradual. Events and states can start or stop suddenly or slowly. There are predicates that cover all of these possibilities, and more.

Causative verbs, like *kill, darken, bring, wake,* and *inflate,* all have the sense of
`Cause to Become` for states, and `Cause to Happen` for events.

- *Frankie killed Johnnie* means 'Frankie caused Johnnie to die'
- *The paint darkens the room* means 'The paint causes the room to become dark(er)'
- *Mary brought John to the party* means 'Mary caused John to arrive at the party'
- *They woke me early today* means 'They caused me to become awake early today'
- *She inflated the balloon properly* means 'She caused the balloon to become properly inflated'

Like *Positive, Comparative*, and *Superlative* (*big, bigger, biggest*, the three degrees of comparison), *Causative* comes as part of a triad, in fact the top of it.

Both active and stative predicates can have beginnings and endings -- changes of state. Predicates that refer to change of state are called *Inchoative* (pronounced /ɪn **ko** ə tɪv/). *Begin, start, finish, stop, end,* and *continue* are basic inchoative verbs. But practically any predicate has an inchoative and a causative counterpart, if there is any need to refer to change or causes of change -- and there usually is.

Sometimes these three predicates are different words, like

- stative *dead*, inchoative *die*, causative *kill* (often the stative is a predicate adjective)

but more often they are simply different forms, nominal, adjective, or verbal, of the same root:

- *broken, break, break* (often the causative and inchoative have the same shape)
- *have* (as 'possess'), *get* (as 'receive'), *get* (as 'retrieve')

[*Get*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104219/15299), in particular, is a very handy verb; it can be used with practically any predicate adjective (and as *get to be*, with practically any predicate noun; the *to be* is optional with predicate adjectives) to indicate either inchoative 'become' or causative 'cause/make'.

- *He was tired/active/writing/kissed today.* (states and events)
- *He got tired/active/writing/kissed today.* (states and events becoming)
- *`Indef` got him tired/active/writing/kissed today.* (states and events being caused)

`Stative/Active - Inchoative - Causative` is just one set of many [characteristic types of predicate](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Predicatetypes.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation. I think I better understand where causative verb classification fits. However, let's (pun partially intended) go back to "let" and "allow" and that while they may participate in causative constructions, they are not actually causative verbs. So what does that make them? They don't seem to be "stative" so that would seem to make them "active"?

Comment: @tangosquared Are you thinking that *I had him sing for his supper* and *I let him sing for his supper* both seem causative to you because both result in the same end state? *Let* has something of a deontic sense here, because it involves permissions -- but positively like *allow, bid* not privatively like *deny, forbid*.