# Correct usage between two word conceive and pregnant

Tags: word-usage, differences, phrase-usage

I am confused about the 2 terms used to say that a lady is bearing a life/child in her womb, they are as follows:-

1. To conceive a child.
2. Getting pregnant.

Are they used differently with time like if you say she conceived a child in the first confirmation of getting pregnant and she is pregnant after some time?

Comment: To "conceive a child" is very formal--to the point of medicalese. It refers to the actual joining of sperm and ovum. "Get pregnant" is less definite, and less formal.

Comment: "Pregnant" is a state, not an act.

Comment: @HotLicks "Get" pregnant indicates  a _change in state_. One of the many uses of _get_.  See John Lawler's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547046/what-kind-of-verb-classification-is-causative/547059#547059)  on this.

Comment: @Cascabel - Yes, and "pregnant" is an adjective, while "conceive" is a noun.

Comment: I had not conceived of a discussion so pregnant with dispute.

Comment: BTW @HotLicks "conceive" is not a noun. It is a verb, like "get". _Conception_ is the noun. You seem off-games today.

Comment: @Cascabel - Oops!!  Brain fart!!!

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah..I have had a lot of those recently. My sympathies.

Comment: @Cascabel - Just be thankful that you don't have to deal with my other farts!